# Split long text in a formula

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I need to insert a formula containing text within. My problem is this text is long and it goes way over the margins, so I am trying to split the line so it could nicely fit in the page. Nothing I have tried so far worked, I am asking you for a bit of help.

```
\begin{description}
    \item[Caso $\bm{\Leftarrow}$] È verificato per i teoremi della sezione \ref{closprop}.
    \item[Caso $\bm{\Rightarrow}$] Sia $L$ un linguaggio regolare tale che $L = L(\mathcal{M})$, 
                  $\mathcal{M}$ è un DFA con stati $q_1, \ldots, q_n$,  
                  definito come di consueto e sia $A = \{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_k\}$. 
                  Definiamo l'insieme $R^k_{i,j}$ nel modo seguente:
                ${R^k_{i,j} = \left\{x \in A^* \mid \delta^*(q_i, x) = q_j \text{ e } \mathcal{M} 
                \text{ nel processare la stringa passa solo per stati } q_l \text { con } l \leq k\right\}}$
    \end{description}
```

Here it is my issue:

[image]

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Please always put a complete small document _in the question_ not as a link (which might change)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd just lift the text out of the math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Caso $\Leftarrow$] È verificato per i teoremi della sezione 
\item[Caso $\Rightarrow$] Sia $L$ un linguaggio regolare tale che $L = L(\mathcal{M})$, $\mathcal{M}$ è un DFA con stati $q_1, \ldots, q_n$, definito come di consueto e sia $A = \{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_k\}$. Definiamo l'insieme $R^k_{i,j}$ nel modo seguente:
$\displaystyle
R^k_{i,j} = \{x \in A^* \mid \delta^*(q_i, x) = q_j \text{ e } \mathcal{M}$  nel processare la stringa passa solo per stati 
$\displaystyle q_l \text { con } l \leq k\}$
\end{description}


\end{document}
```

Or with a `center` environment around the display:

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. I really need it to be in display style rather than inline.

Comment: It is in display style: `\displaystyle` you could put it (both math sections and the text in between) inside a center environment if you want it to be set off from the preceding paragraph

Comment: @haunted85 see 2nd image added to answer